# How to search from values from one table in another one?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I got a table that stores some employee names.

```
      ID              Name       
    -------------------------------
    01                  Mark
    02                  John
    03                  Macy
    04                  Drey
    05                  Ivan
    06                  Eduard 
    07                  Mary
    08                  Duley
```

I got a pivot table like (note that the keys are known, but not the value each of them will store, dates for instance):

```
      ID              Reference          Key               Value
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    01                  001             date                03/04/2009
    02                  001             shift               1st
    03                  001             station a           Mark
    04                  001             station b           John
    05                  001             station b           Macy
    06                  002             date                04/04/2009
    07                  002             shift               2nd
    08                  002             station a           John
    09                  002             Station a           Drey
    10                  002             Station b           Macy
```

And i would like to have:

```
    Operator         Dates             1st Shift    2nd shift   A Station  B Station
    ---------+-----------------------+------------+------------+----------+--------
    Mark      03/04/2009                   2              0           1        0
    John      03/04/2009, 04/04/2013       1              1           1        1
    Macy      03/04/2009, 04/04/2009       1              1           0        2
    Drey      04/04/2009                   0              1           1        0
```

In other words: "Dates" column show the days each employ worked. The other columns count the number of times each employee worked at each station and on each shift.

It would also be great if query could be fit in a view....

Tx a lot!

Comment: are the keys already defined (i.e. the keys are "deterministic"), or will you  add more keys in the future?

Comment: they are predefined....no more keys in the future. only more/less (different) values (employees, shifts and dates).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not pretty, and it may take quite a time executing in your production environment, but the fact that your data lacks a stable grouping component makes this difficult to do efficiently.

So, try this:

```
SELECT e.`Name`
  , (select group_concat(`Value`) from shiftinfo where `Key` = 'date' and Reference in (select Reference from shiftinfo where `Value` = e.`Name`)) as Dates
  , (select count(Reference) from shiftinfo where `Key` = 'shift' and `Value` = '1st' and Reference in (select Reference from shiftinfo where `Value` = e.`Name`)) as `1st Shift`
  , (select count(Reference) from shiftinfo where `Key` = 'shift' and `Value` = '2nd' and Reference in (select Reference from shiftinfo where `Value` = e.`Name`)) as `2nd Shift`
  , (select count(Reference) from shiftinfo where `Key` = 'station a' and `Value` = e.`Name`) as `Station A`
  , (select count(Reference) from shiftinfo where `Key` = 'station b' and `Value` = e.`Name`) as `Station B`
FROM employee e;
```

We subselect based on employee names for everything in part because there's no single way to get all the data you want.

See the demo [here on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d942/7).

Comment: Tx a lot @Jazz. Can u help me to filter my results? I need to filter by: a) only last month dates b) only results that regards the 2 shift. Tx once more